# Qgis raster interpolation shift

Tags: qgis, raster, interpolation

Using Qgis 2.0.1, I'm attempting to interpolate a large point dataset (n > 400K) to a raster surface.

I'm using the IDW option in `Raster>> Interpolation>> Interpolation`, and the resulting output surface has an inexplicable shift 100 metres southwards of the orginal point grid. Can't find the cause of the problem. Has anyone encountered anything like this before?

Comment: Which CRS are used for the data? It would be easiest to test if you could share a sample dataset and a screenshot of the settings you used.

Comment: It sounds like we might have a similar situation. I wrote up an inexplicable transform in a processed raster in [this ticket](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/81694/where-is-this-raster-offset-being-introduced-in-the-qgis-processing-toolbox). Does it look like your problem?